# Remote printing doesn't work.  Remote XP, Local Windows 7

Tags: remote-desktop, printer, printing

I have a friend that is using remote desktop to access her office desktop (XP) from her home desktop (Windows 7).

She wants to print from the remote box to the local one (XP to 7).

She has the "Share Printers" check box checked in the connection properties, but the local printers won't show up in the remote printers folder.  I'm not all that familiar with remote desktop, but it seems like it might be an issue with 7.

Are there any changes in 7 that would cause this, or any other ideas why the printers don't show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your friend is remoting into a corporate environment, it is possible that they have [disabled printer redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791784(WS.10).aspx), as that is what is done at my company.  I believe that clipboard sharing can also be disabled via Group Policy.  Has this ever worked in the past?

Comment: She says it worked previously, when she had XP on both ends.  The only thing that's really changed is the local box changed to 7.

Answer (score 0):

XP to 7 - it may be a driver issue, I'm not sure as I have never done this.

However, I worked a problem the other day and found that "host based printers" will not carry over in to RDP sessions. Typically, consumer model printers are host based. What is the make/model of the printer your friend is using on her Windows 7 computer?

Comment: It's an HP of some type.  I forget the model.  I'll check next time I see it, but it was working for this printer before, so it's probably not host based?

Answer (score 0):

another option:

> With **[PrinterAnywhere](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/PrinterAnywhere.shtml)** you will
>   be able to print documents and photos
>   on other people's printers as easily
>   as on the local one connected to your
>   machine. No special technical
>   knowledge is required from both -
>   printer owner and user. It just works!

... like Skype for printers :)

*PrintAnywhere is freeware.*